# Cometchat is it actually using comet?

Tags: comet

So someone's selling a comet chat solution:
http://www.cometchat.com/

But I think it might be a misnomer, because I don't think it actually uses comet.

Can someone confirm whether or not it's actually a comet based chat, or just o' ajax.

Thanks.

Comment: I tentatively agree, it doesn't "seem" to use comet, as I don't see the page continually loading, and it seems to use a few jQuery .post functions.

Comment: The offer [CometService](http://www.cometchat.com/cometservice) which uses actual comet/long-polling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTM - According to their FAQ they do not.
http://www.cometchat.com/support/page/faq?category=6

Comment: In fact, CometChat offers you PubNub Real-time Network TCP Sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that depends

Do you use true Comet technology?
By default CometChat is set to use smart-polling i.e. CometChat will poll depending on user activity. Taken from their website **"If you activate our CometService, then CometChat will switch over to true Comet technology."**

I suspect that you can also use true comet technology with cometchat in conjunction with ApeServer, BeaconPush or PusherApp, but you'd be best to email them directly to find out.